# Close started Activity

Tags: android

I am starting following activity:

```
Intent messageIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, Uri.parse(SMS_PREFIX + number));
context.startActivity(messageIntent);
```

I want to close it immediately like:

```
context.startActivity(messageIntent);
context.stopActivity(messageIntent);
```

How can I do it ?

Comment: Are you owner of the Activity that will receive the messageIntent?

Comment: @DroidBender No, I'm not.

Comment: Then you can not close the Activity :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK you can't.

Activities are finished either by user interaction (AKA: back button) or with an explicit call to `finish();`  [https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish%28%29)

`finish()` is a public method, so if you have a direct reference to the instance of the activity you can call if from whatever object you want. But not implicitly via intent.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you calling startActivity in first place?

If you need to do that , you can call **finish()** in **oncreate()** method of the new activity and then it will close  immediately.

Comment: As you can see, I'm calling external activity, so I'm not able to do this.

Comment: Ok, in this case you can't close it AFAIK.